# Undefined symbols error when prototype matches function

Tags: c++, function

I am creating a game of Tic Tac Toe. I am trying to initialize a grid, which will be a 2 dimensional vector.
Here is my main code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

#include "ttt_functions.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector< vector<int> > grid = initialize();
    for (vector <int> i : grid) {
        for (int j : i) {
            cout << j << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Here is my prototype file (.hpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector< vector<int> > initialize();
```

And here are my functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
vector< vector<int> > initialize(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
        std::vector<int> new_vec(0,3);
        grid.push_back(new_vec);
    }
    return grid;
}
```

I have consistently run into this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "initialize()", referenced from:
      _main in ttt-15c935.o
```

I have looked at other stack overflows and they said the error is a problem with the prototype not matching the function, but I cut and copied the prototype onto the function so I know they are identical and I am still getting this error. Please advice, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Undefined symbols" suggests to me a problem with linking. How are you compiling the code?

Answer (score 2):

Your third file which contains the `initalize()` function body should include the header (prototype) file with function declaration.

Comment: I added "#include "ttt_functions.hpp""to the final section of code shown above (the function body section), and it is still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: I wasn't compiling with the functions files, so I was getting the error. I compiled instead with both files named , like this:

```
g++ ttt.cpp ttt_functions.cpp
```